# Replace multiple words in pig

Tags: replace, apache-pig

I am new to Pig. In the script that I am writing I want to perform an operation similar to this:

```
foreach X GENERATE REPLACE(word,'.*abc.*','abc') OR REPLACE(word,'.*def.*','def').
```

If the first pattern matches then `abc` is replaced else if second pattern is matched then `def` is replaced. But I suppose the syntax is incorrect. Can someone help me with the syntax?

Comment: Do you want to replace both if they both match? Or do you only want to replace `def` if `abc` is not found? Do you really want to replace the entire word?

Comment: so if the sentence has pqabcpq, then it should be replaced to abc. and if the sentence has iudefqw, it should be replaced to def. Token contains only one word, hence only abc or def will be present at a time. So I have a set of tokens eg. (pqdsabceq.wqwowqabceqw,ewedefweqe), I should get (abc,abc,def).

Comment: Ok. What if you have `(pqdsabceq.wqwowqabceqw,ewedefweqe,iluabcwedefagh)`? Or can you guarantee they never co-occur?

Comment: yes. I can guarantee that the token will only contain either abc or def or neither, but not both at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few ways to do this, but since if the regex doesn't match the string, you'll just get your string back, this is pretty compact:

```
Y = FOREACH X GENERATE REPLACE(REPLACE(word, '.*abc.*', 'abc'), '.*def.*', 'def');
```

Comment: Thanks... that worked...really stupid of me not to think this way...anyways thank you for the reply.